# reshape dataframe time series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have a dataframe for a weather data in certain shape and i want to transform it, but struggling on it.
My dataframe looks like that :

```
    city temp_day1, temp_day2, temp_day3 ...., hum_day1, hum_day2, hum_day4, ..., condition
    

    city_1      12         13             20         44      44.5    good          44  
    city_1      12         13             20         44      44.5
```

bad            44
city_2      14         04             33         44      44.5
good           44

I want to transforme it to

```
    city_1                                   city_2                          .....
day. temperature humidity condition ...   temperature humidity condition

1      12           44      good .          12         13             
20         44      44.5 
2      13           44 .5   bad  . 
3      20           NaN     bad  .
4      NaN          44       .
```

some day dont have temperature values and humidity values

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and last [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                       stubnames=['temp','hum'], 
                       i='city', 
                       j='day', 
                       sep='_', 
                       suffix='\w+')
        .unstack(0)
        .swaplevel(1,0, axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1))
print (df1)
city city_1      
        hum  temp
day              
day1   44.0  12.0
day2   44.5  13.0
day3    NaN  20.0
day4   44.0   NaN
```

Alternative solution:

```
df1 = df.set_index('city')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.stack([0,1]).unstack([0,1])
```

---

If need extract numbers from `index`:

```
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                       stubnames=['temp','hum'], 
                       i='city', 
                       j='day', 
                       sep='_', 
                       suffix='\w+')
        .unstack(0)
        .swaplevel(1,0, axis=1)
        .sort_index(axis=1))

df1.index = df1.index.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
print (df1)
city city_1      
        hum  temp
day              
1      44.0  12.0
2      44.5  13.0
3       NaN  20.0
4      44.0   NaN
```

EDIT:

Solution with real data:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['condition', 'ACTIVE', 'mode', 'apply', 'spy', 'month'], append=True) 
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True) 
df1 = df1.stack([0,1]).unstack([0,-2])
```

If need remove unnecessary levels in `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=['condition', 'ACTIVE', 'mode', 'apply', 'spy', 'month'], drop=True)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224553/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-reshape-dataframe-time-series).

Comment: I putted a screen shot of the data

Comment: I putted a sample because there are more than 300 columns

Comment: I just removed the picture, sorry

Comment: how to share data file ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t-DokIKyPYwKKPPq_oE95nfAm-yYQX4q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you access ?

Comment: Super, now testing this data, can you show me what is wrong? How looks expected output from sample data shared above? Can you share first 2-3 rows of good expected output?

Comment: I want to have as index the  time extracted from TMP_-1min .. column name and by city_code.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16a9dTa-_r0yVyBSyVHa2xTu4qnqdvuVa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to have a dataframe by same city_id, and the index will be day

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas transpose method like this: df.T

This will turn your dataframe into one row. If you create multiple columns, you can slice it with indexing and assing each slice to independent columns.